# How to center a container and align its elements to the left using flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm using material UI for a project and right now I'm facing a problem using flex-box. I'm creating Cards using material UI, and what I need to do is center the parent container without centering its items.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import { Stack } from "@mui/material";

let arreglo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const LizardCard = () => {
  return (
    //This are the items I want to be aligned to the left inside the container.
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345, boxShadow: "0px 2px 5px", alignSelf: "left" }}>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="140"
        image="https://mui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
        alt="green iguana"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
          Lizard
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
          Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
          species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">Share</Button>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

const Test = () => {
  return (
    // <Box
    //   sx={{
    //     display: "flex",
    //     justifyContent: "center",
    //     flexFlow: "row wrap",
    //   }}
    // >

    // This is the container, it is already centered but the items go to the center too
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "left",
        flexFlow: "row wrap",
      }}
    >
      {arreglo.map((x) => {
        return <LizardCard />;
      })}
    </Box>
    // </Box>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

This is an example using the code above:
[image: Example]

I want that second row to look as the first one, those 2 elements to the left instead of center.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
[image: Answer test]

This is how it looks with Mohammed's answer.
the only modification I did was:

```
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
}

.flex-parent::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
```

Comment: `justifyContent: "center",` -> `justifyContent: "flex-start",` or just remove that line.

Comment: As I see in the second screenshot I think the parent has some spacing in both sides so you need to wrap them in an inner container to align them together and make this container take the width you need and make that container the flex parent to them

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary to make `justify-content: "center"` you can just make it `justify-content: "flex-start"`. If it is necessary to leave like it is so you can parent the parent `::after` fill the space like this:

```
.flex-parent {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.flex-parent::after {
   content: "";
   flex: auto;
}
```

Then this will make your last row to start from the beginning.

Comment: I tried this just adding the flex-direction and the flex-wrap, and it kind of works, now the problem is that the second row overflows the container to the left.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: sure, edited the question with the changes I did too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Debugging the I can see the ::after is filling up a the space that is making the other to elements go more to the left.